# Rotate picture according to Cursor move direction

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to rotate a picture according the direction in which the cursor is moved.
Here is some code, I wrote for trying:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
        <!-- uncomment lines below to include extra p5 libraries -->
        <!--<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/addons/p5.dom.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>-->
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="asd.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    </body>

</html>
```

My JavaScript file is as follows:

```
function preload() {
    arrowImg = loadImage("fish.png");
}

// Creating canvas
function setup() {
    createCanvas(600, 300);
    background(255);
    noCursor();
}

// Displaying the functions above
function draw() {
    background(255);
    imageMode(CENTER);
    image(arrowImg, mouseX, mouseY, arrowImg.width / 10, arrowImg.height / 10);
}
```

[image]

How is it possible to get the attributes in what direction the cursor or mouse is moving in processing/p5js and how is it possible to rotate a picture 180 degrees?

The idea was: the image is following the cursor. If the cursor moves right, the image is staying as it is. the cursor moves left, the image rotates 180 degree

Answer (score 0):

I’m not quite sure i,ve understood your problem but i think that you can add rotate() function from p5js before you draw the image.

About the rotation relatively with your mouse position you can save the coordonates of the mouse and make some simple math with cartesian coordonates to calculate the angle you need.

Comment: The idea was: the image is following the cursor. If the cursor moves right, the image is staing as it is. he cursor moves left, the image rotates 180 degree

Answer (score 0):

I have same questions. 
after a fews hours researched, I found this way:

```
    let fish;
    function preload() {
        fish = loadImage('images/fish.png');
    }

    function setup() {
        createCanvas(600, 600);
    }

    function draw() {
        background(0);
        var imgx = 300;
        var imgy = 300;
        var angle = atan2(mouseY - imgy, mouseX - imgx);
        push();
        translate(imgx, imgy);
        rotate(angle);
        imageMode(CENTER);
        image(fish, 0, 0, 80, 50)
        pop();
    }
```

The key point here are `imageMode(CENTER);`:

```
        translate(imgx, imgy);
        rotate(angle);
        imageMode(CENTER);
```

Hope it help. Thanks